# People picker not able to fetch one user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, administration, people-picker

I am trying to fetch user in people picker. However, in the Production Environment it is failing to resolve one of the user in few of the sitecollection. When I try to get the same user in other sitecollections in the same webapplication , the user is resolvable there(These are recently created sitecollections).
On UAT environment this is occuring for the whole farm on every single web application.

Other observations and informations:-

1. Authentication providers - Windows
2. User present in Mange User Profile
3. On UAT                   - Not resolvable anywhere
4. It is not resolvable in central administration site.

I have already tried the following:

1. Turned off firewall on test.(not worked)
2. Checked the user in server manager -- > user groups(user is present there)  (IN TEST SERVER)

3.Used Powershell command (NewSPUser) to set it for site collection, However it is giving error - user not recognized

Any Clues?

Comment: have you configured User Profile Synchronization.?

Comment: People picker gets users directly from AD .So user profile configuration will not effect.However to answer your question,Yes the User Profile is configured and user is present there.

Comment: As per my understanding, people picker will not access AD directly, first it will check the user in User Information List. Are you able to add the user into a group.?

Comment: No, For adding the user in a group I will have to add it using people picker,which is not able to resolve the users.

Answer (score 1):

I have **resolved** the issue.

It was occuring because the account was disabled at Active Directory level.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: @BennySkogberg - actually, this seems more like a self-answered question. Anyway Rameez, glad you found a solution - remember that you can also accept your own answer when the timeout expires (two days if I recall correctly)

Comment: also +1 - this **is** an answer, not a simple "thank you".

Comment: @SPArchaeologist My bad! I read it wrong. No offence intended.

Comment: @BennySkogberg - Don't worry. My only concern was that the answer could get deleted by error.

Comment: Hi Yes this is a self answered question...Is there any way so that i can mark it as answer